# No encuentro eclipse 4.12 - 32 bit para windows

Tags: eclipse

No actualizo eclipse desde hace un año. Actualmente uso la versión 4.8. y se que ahora están por la 4.12.
He tratado de descargarme la versión platform 4.12, pero solo viene la de 64 bits que al instalarla me da el típico error code 13 debido a la incompatibilidad de versiones pues tengo windows de 64 bits pero java de 32, y eclipse debe ser también de 32 bits.

Me gustaría usar eclipse y java de 64 bits, pero dependo de una librería que solo soporta 32 bits.

Donde está el  link a la platform binary para windows de 32 bits?
No la encuentro!

Answer (score 0):

Buscando en google...https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32.zip Yo tiraría de Java 64bits porque vas a tener problemas de compatibilidad si no lo tienes ya en un futuro cercano